# File explorer closes when I attempt to log in to a network location

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a USB printer that is connected to one PC in our network. Because it is currently the only printer in the office, the best way I found to set this printer up, is to share it to the other PCs in the LAN.

Now, the host PC (PC1) is connected to the domain, using Windows 10 Professional, and all the other PCs are using Windows 10 Home. When I attempt to connect to the shared printer on PC1, I have to login to the PC1 network location (`\\PC1\`) as the Administrator (i.e. `domain\admin`). I can then connect to the printer, and all is fine.

However, since all of the PCs are laptops, they often are taken home at the end of the day, and disconnected, meaning that they need to be re-connected every time they come back in, and I'm getting tired of having to set up this connection over and over.

So I attempted to change the sharing rules to add in another user, on another PC (PC2) allowing them to set this up for themselves, logging in using their own credentials (i.e. `domain\username`), without having to give them the Admin credentials (an obvious no-no).

However, when the user attempts to log in to `\\PC1\` from their computer (PC2), using their credentials, the Windows Explorer would refresh (the taskbar would disappear, then reappear) but the only window that would close is the File Explorer.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you use the 'net use' cmd to map a drive to it and copy files?

Comment: @Citizen I'm not trying to access a shared folder, it's a shared printer?

Comment: They are both advertised as SMB (server message block).  Answer will cut the issues in half.  If you can map a drive and copy files without issue you know that may not be a network issue and something to do with the translation of browsing (\\servername\printername) to the UI.